# CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} - Microsoft.Office.Interop.excel.dll error

Tags: windows-installer, vsto

We have created one small excel application using Microsoft.Office.Interop.excel.dll
We want to ship this application on client side.  Configuration of system is as below.
   1) It is a sharepoint server 2010.
   2) It has office webapp installed.
Customer is not able to install office 2010 on top of 'office webapp'.

Problem: while running the application we are receiving below error message:

```
Exception for while Processing the file; error is: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with
 CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 
80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

Many pepole are facing this problem and as per the existing blogs the only solution is to install office 2010 ( Which we cant do because its not possible to install office 2010 on top of 'office webapp', seems to be a technical problem.)

so we built a custom MSI package using C# .Net and deployed all the dependent files of.
'Microsoft.Office.Interop.excel.dll' ( including office.dll )

Still we are getting the same error.  It is not possible to distribute office.dll?  Is it a licencing related problem? Is there any way to overcome the problem?
Customer is ready to buy the licence but can't install it because of some technical problem.

Thanks in advance,
Hemant

Comment: I don't know if this is intentional or the customer just refuses to install Office.  Which is very understandable, Microsoft does not recommend nor support running Office on a server.  Office programs are *heavy* and only designed to run on a workstation.  On a server it takes but a few clients to connect to the server and get the Office app started before the server grinds to a halt.  You'd better write this off and start looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only redistributable available is the [VSTO Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35594). However, my understanding is the same as the advice you already received, you need the Office client bits installed to interoperate with the Office applications. The webapps do not qualify.